# Laravel 5.8 How do you Custom Reset Password Email (email content only and links)

Tags: laravel, email, passwords

Laravel 5.8 how do you Custom Reset Password Email (email content only and links)?

Comment: please send some code of what you do and what you expect and what you get

Comment: `php artisan vendor:publish` Then modify the file here `/resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php`

Comment: @sta  I've published the asset, What if we want to change the Laravel text, with the brand logo for example, and since the default reset password button links to localhost, can we just change it on .env? because even in the email.blade.php it's calling variables from I dont know where..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing these variables in `.env` file

`APP_NAME=`
`APP_URL=`